# JQuery - непонятное бездействие

Tags: jquery, ajax

Недавно долго возился с ajax, задавал тут вопрос, и не без помощи изучал, как он работает. Решил разработать мини-чат, но что-то пошло не так: внешний файл ajax.js со скриптами подключен, но не работает, скрипты в нем работают только при написании их в `<script></script>`, но и здесь случилось что-то совершенно сверхъестественное: написал скрипт для отправки сообщений, он какое-то время работал и бац - просто на ровном месте перестал. Я ничего не менял, все перепроверил - непонятно. Что делать с этим ajaxом, чтобы он работал? Все php скрипты исправны.

Ajax код:

```
function refresh_chat() {

$.get("action/chat_sql.php", function(text){ 
        $(".chat_block").html(text);
    });

}


$(".send").click ( 

function() { 

 $.get("action/chat_send.php?message="+$('.text').val(), function(){ 
        $(".text").val('');
        refresh_chat();
    });

} 

);


refresh_chat(); 
t = setInterval(refresh_chat, 2000);
```

Comment: ну дак что из них перестало работать то? отправка? в базу заносятся? или выборка? зы: используйте лучше пост-запрос для отправки.

Comment: в базу все заносится, если отдельно перейти, допустим, в chat_send.php, то все сработает. А через вот этот ajax код уже ничего не заносится, даже `$(".text").val('');` не работает

Comment: В консоли есть ошибки при отправке ?

Comment: Теперь и вывод сообщений сам по себе перестал работать, выводит ошибку: Failed to load https://www.chat.com/action/chat_sql.php: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://chat.com' is therefore not allowed access. При отправке нет ошибок

Comment: вы на другой домен что ли отправляете?

Comment: Я на локальном сервере просто другой домен создал. В общем, я понял, там document ready не хватало. Почему-то ранее, когда он был прописан во внешнем скрипте, он не работал